# RSpec: difference between "should == ..." and "should eql(...)"

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

In RSpec, what's the difference between using `should == ...` and `should eql(...)`? I noticed that the RSpec documentation always uses `eql`, but `==` is less typing and easier to read. What am I missing?

Comment: http://batsov.com/articles/2011/11/28/ruby-tip-number-1-demystifying-the-difference-between-equals-equals-and-eql/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's rather simple, really: `should ==` sends the `==` message to the test subject, `should eql` sends the `eql?` message to the test subject. In other words: the two different tests send two completely different messages which invoke two completely different methods and thus do two completely different things. In particular, `eql?` is stricter than `==` but less strict than `equals?`.

Answer (score 15):

They are usually equivalent, but not always:

```
1 ==   1.0 # => true
1.eql? 1.0 # => false
```