# Why is eql more common in RSpec specs than eql? in normal code?

Tags: ruby, rspec, equality

In many Ruby or Ruby on Rails projects using RSpec, `eql` is used fairly frequently within spec files, but `eql?` is rarely used outside of spec files, while `==` is used infrequently within spec files, but frequently outside of spec files.

For example, looking at the spree project:

```
spree agrimm$ git grep eql **/spec/**/* | wc
     135     589   14976
spree agrimm$ git grep eql | wc
     138     600   15274
spree agrimm$ git grep '==' **/spec/**/* | wc
      56     413    5764
spree agrimm$ git grep '==' | wc
    1165   11857  297297
```

I understand the [difference in functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285199/rspec-difference-between-should-and-should-eql) between `==` and `eql?`. But why do people frequently choose to use `eql` (which is a matcher which corresponds to `eql?`) (for example `expect(a).to eql(b)`) in RSpec rather than `==` (for example `expect(a).to be == b`)?

Comment: This reminds me of the [Robustness principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle). Within my specs, I usually want to be strict. A method returning `0` instead of the expected `0.0` should fail the test. In code however, I'm on the "consumer side" and tend to be liberal. Here, a method returning `0` instead of the expected `0.0` should not break my code.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, rather than definite knowledge. Other people may know for sure.

```
# Tests whether a == b
expect(a).to be == b
```

doesn't look as nice as

```
# Tests whether a.eql?(b)
expect(a).to eql(b)
```

but some users aren't aware you can use `eq` to give

```
# Tests whether a == b
expect(a).to eq(b)
```

The Spree project uses `eq` fairly frequently:

```
spree agrimm$ git grep eq **/spec/**/* | wc
    2930   11694  320369
```

Comment: I never use `eql`, for example. Only `eq`.

Answer (score -1):

`==` occurs infrequently in current RSpec files because the `==` matcher is not supported by the preferred `expect` syntax. It occurs frequently in implementation files because it is the more natural syntax.

Similarly, `eql` (and `eq`) occur frequently in RSpec because they are the matchers for `eql?` and `==`, respectively. There is little need for them in production because `==` predominates.